# Deployment error

Tags: iphone, xcode, deployment, ios

Hi all i am getting deployment error when i try to run my app in the device. it says "no provisioning ios devices are connected".
I have ios sdk 4.1 installed on my mac and in the device the version of ios is 4.2. I have conected my device to Mac.

Can i run my app under these conditions or i need to update ios sdk to 4.2 in Mac also.

if yes then is there any update available so that i can update my sdk from version 4.1 to 4.2 or i have to download the whole new version of 4.2 (almost 3.5 GB).

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. The testing device's version canNOT be higher than your Xcode's version.
2. I think you'll have to download the entire new one since Xcode doesn't provide a way to just update. (If I was wrong, please correct me)